# update row from source sheet to destination sheet but only on selected columns

Tags: excel, vba

the 2nd pic is the source sheet in sheet2 it will find the "race" row with the same value in the 1st pic sheet1 then update each column when found, as you can see it has different column structure, what could be the fastest way it could update the destination sheet when it has thousands of rows to loop?

destination - sheet1
[image: destination - Sheet1]

source- sheet2

[image: source - Sheet2]

desired result - sheet1

[image: result - Sheet1]

Comment: Please share your code so we can build on it. Does the destination contain only values or are there also formulas?

Comment: The headers are different, but **will they be all the time as we can see in the pictures**? Or they may be changing? If so, in both sheets?

Comment: @VBasic2008 code works great, had no initial code since dont know how to match non contiguous colum name using array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update Data

```vb
Sub UpdateData()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Read source.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    Dim shrg As Range, sData(), shData(), srCount As Long, scCount As Long
    
    With sws.UsedRange
        srCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        scCount = .Columns.Count
        Set shrg = .Resize(1)
        shData = shrg.Value
        sData = .Resize(srCount).Offset(1).Value
    End With
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim sr As Long, sString As String
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        sString = CStr(sData(sr, 1))
        If Len(sString) > 0 Then
            dict(sString) = sr
        End If
    Next sr
    
    ' Read destination.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim drg As Range, dhrg As Range, dData(), drCount As Long
    
    With dws.UsedRange
        drCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        Set dhrg = .Resize(1)
        Set drg = .Resize(drCount).Offset(1)
        dData = drg.Value
    End With
    
    Dim dcIndices(): dcIndices = Application.Match(shrg, dhrg, 0)
    
    ' Update.
    
    Dim sc As Long, dr As Long, dc As Long, dString As String
    
    For dr = 1 To drCount
        dString = CStr(dData(dr, 1))
        If dict.Exists(dString) Then
            sr = dict(dString)
            For sc = 2 To scCount
                dc = dcIndices(sc)
                dData(dr, dc) = sData(sr, sc)
            Next sc
        End If
    Next dr

    ' Write.

    drg.Value = dData

    ' Inform.

    MsgBox "Data updated.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next way. It is able to match columns even if their order will differ in the future. It should be very fast, using arrays and processing being done mostly in memory:

```
Sub UpdateSheet1DiffColsOrder()
   Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, lastR As Long, lastCol As Long
   Dim arr1, arrH1, arr2, arrH2, arrMtch, i As Long, j As Long
   
   Set sh1 = Workshets("Sheet1") 'use here the sheet to be processed
   Set sh2 = Workshets("Sheet2") 'use here the sheet to extract data from
   
   lastCol = sh1.cells(1, sh1.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column
   
   With Application
        arrH1 = sh1.Range(sh1.cells(1, 1), sh1.cells(1, lastCol)).Value 'place the header from Sheet1 in an array
        
        lastCol = sh2.cells(1, sh2.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column 'calculate last column in Sheet2
        arrH2 = sh2.Range(sh2.cells(1, 1), sh2.cells(1, lastCol)).Value 'place the header from Sheet2 in an array
        
        arrMtch = .IfError(.match(arrH2, arrH1, 0), 0)  'match the two header arrays replacing with 0 the not matching cases
         mtch = .match(0, arrMtch, 0) 'checking if some header(s) do not match
          If Not IsError(mtch) Then _
             MsgBox arrH2(1, mtch) & " does not match any string in the other header...": Exit Sub
   End With
   
   lastR = sh1.Range("A" & sh1.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   arr1 = sh1.Range("A2:L" & lastR).Value 'place the range to be processed in an array, for faster iteration/processing
   
   arr2 = sh2.Range("A2:G2").Value 'place the range where from to extract data in an array
   
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr1)                          'iterate between the array row
        If arr1(i, 1) = arr2(1, 1) Then               'if a match in their first column
            For j = 1 To UBound(arrMtch)              'iterate between the matching array elements
                If arrMtch(j) <> 0 Then               'if a match has been found
                    arr1(i, arrMtch(j)) = arr2(1, j)  'extract the value in the matched column
                End If
            Next j
        End If
   Next i
   
   'Drop back the processed array at once:
   sh1.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arr1), UBound(arr1, 2)).Value = arr1
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: thanks tested your code it is flexible with different columns, just want to ask where in the code do i change if the compare column changes, from my initial setup the compare column is find race no. in column A of sheet2 in column A of sheet1, what about if the race no. is in column C of sheet2 and the race no. is in column E of sheet1?

Comment: p.s. wish i could accept both code of yours and vbasic2008 as answers, i only accepted his code as the answer coz he was first, thanks again!

Comment: @k1dr0ck Then, you should adapt the next line: `If arr1(i, 1) = arr2(1, 1) Then`. For the case you mentioned above it should become `If arr1(i, 5) = arr2(1, 3) Then`. I mean, the second 2D array parameter represents the column...

Comment: @k1dr0ck As a matter o fact, the code can be updated to use two constants relevantly named for the respective two columns...